# How do you convert the multi-line content scraped into a list?

Tags: regex, python-2.7, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I was trying to convert the content scraped into a list for data manipulation, but got the following error: TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable

```
#! /usr/bin/python

from urllib import urlopen
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup
import os
import re

# Copy all of the content from the provided web page
webpage = urlopen("http://www.optionstrategist.com/calculators/free-volatility-    data").read()

# Grab everything that lies between the title tags using a REGEX
preBegin = webpage.find('<pre>') # Locate the pre provided
preEnd = webpage.find('</pre>') # Locate the /pre provided

# Copy the content between the pre tags
voltable = webpage[preBegin:preEnd] 

# Pass the content to the Beautiful Soup Module
raw_data = BeautifulSoup(voltable).splitline()
```

Comment: Use HTML parser (IIRC, there is BeautifulSoup).

Comment: Just realize that you have it imported, but you never use it for extracting the tag and opt for regex instead...

Comment: I added in the new code. But I am having problem converting the content to a list for data manipulation. I got TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable. Raw_data is <type 'instance'>. I have never encounter such situation before.

Comment: All you need for this task: http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all , http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#kinds-of-filters , http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text Learn to read the manual please.

Comment: I did actually. But I don't understand.

Answer (score 0):

The code is very simple. This is the code for BeautifulSoup4:

```
# Find all <pre> tag in the HTML page
preTags = webpage.find_all('pre')

for tag in preTags:
    # Get the text inside the tag
    print(tag.get_text())
```

Reference:

- [find_all()](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#find-all)
- [Kinds of filters to put into name field of find()/findall()](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#kinds-of-filters)
- [get_text()](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#get-text)

Comment: It is not valid Python. OP uses BeautifulSoup 3 that has different spelling for `find_all()`, `get_text()` that are from bs4 version.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: Valid/invalid Python is different from valid code for BS version.

Comment: Your answer is *both*: it has invalid Python syntax *and* it uses API incompatible with the code in the question.

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian: Thanks for the comment about the bad Python syntax. But I don't care whether the BeautifulSoup version is compatible or not.

Answer (score 0):

To get the text from the first `pre` element:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from urllib2 import urlopen
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup

url = "http://www.optionstrategist.com/calculators/free-volatility-data"
soup = BeautifulSoup(urlopen(url))
print soup.pre.string
```

To extract lines with data:

```
from itertools import dropwhile

lines = soup.pre.string.splitlines()
# drop lines before the data table header
lines = dropwhile(lambda line: not line.startswith("Symbol"), lines)
# extract lines with data
lines = (line for line in lines if '%ile' in line)
```

Now each line contains data in a fixed-column format. You could use slicing and/or regex to parse/validate individual fields in each row.